# Unrouted wires double after routing in eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I almost finished routing a PCB but after trying to change the placement of a via to ground plane ripup and route the wire connected to it, I've got a weird airwire which is between a pad and nothing.[image] and when I run run length I got [image]. When I try to route it to the closest via to GND I got new unrouted wires like mentioned in the picture [image]
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is the "nothing" end of the airwire going to something on a different layer that you have hidden right now? Also, does anything change when you do a ratsnest?

Comment: No it leads to nothing in other layers

Comment: Please post a picture with the other copper layers shown. If you have more than one other copper layer, maybe post a picture for each copper layer. When you save the project, exit Eagle, and then open the project, is everything exactly the same?

Comment: Do you hit ratsnest?

Comment: I've noticed this with Eagle a few times when the routed trace doesn't touch what it considers to be the middle of the pad. More pronounced for things that don't align directly to the grid. In this case it looks like you've got a ground plane somewhere else, ratsnest will resolve any polygon fills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CAD packages that save their native database in a binary format can develop internal database errors due to strange corner case software bugs. I've had experience that sometimes this can be worked around by exporting the design to an ASCII format. Then close and re-open the CAD tool and import the ASCII format database into a new design file.

Surprisingly I had a problem very similar to the one you are describing here in a design some 12 years ago that required the "fix" I describe above. That was with PADS software.